# why start a timer in SDL when setting FPS?

Tags: c++, c, sdl, frame-rate

this is regarding [this](http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson14/index.php) tutorial page from lazyfoo's set of SDL tutorials. There he first starts a timer to calculate how much time each frame should stay alive for, before it is refreshed. He does this using the following

```
if( ( cap == true ) && ( fps.get_ticks() < 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND ) ) { 
 //Sleep the remaining frame time 
 SDL_Delay( ( 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND ) - fps.get_ticks() ); 
}
```

Although I've found that fps.get_ticks() always returns 0 (??) and so isn't the above not needed(?), cant we just completely leave out the timer and just delay for 1000/FPS.

I've tried both ways below and both give me the same thing. What am I missing here, why do we need a timer?.

```
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include <iostream>
SDL_Surface *background = NULL;
SDL_Surface *screen = NULL;
SDL_Surface *msg = NULL;
const int FPS = 20;

void initialize(void){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == -1 ){
        std::cout<<"could not start sdl"<<std::endl;
    }

    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640,480,32,SDL_SWSURFACE);
    if (screen == NULL){
        std::cout<<"could not make screen"<<std::endl;
    }

}
void cleanUp(void){
    SDL_Quit();
    SDL_FreeSurface(background);
    SDL_FreeSurface(msg);
}
void loadFiles(void){
    background = IMG_Load("background.bmp");
    msg = IMG_Load("msg.bmp");
    if (background == NULL){
        std::cout<<"could not load background"<<std::endl;
    }
    if (msg == NULL){
        std::cout<<"could not load msg"<<std::endl;
    }
}
void blitSurf(int x,int y,SDL_Surface *source,SDL_Surface *dest){
    SDL_Rect dest_pos;
    dest_pos.x = x;
    dest_pos.y = y;

    if (SDL_BlitSurface(source,NULL,dest,&dest_pos) == -1){
        std::cout<<"could not blit surface"<<std::endl;
    }
}
void update(void){
    if (SDL_Flip(screen) == -1 ){
        std::cout<<"could not update screen"<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    initialize();
    loadFiles();

    bool running = true;
    bool cap = false;
    int msg_pos_y = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    SDL_Event event;
    while (running == true){
        start = SDL_GetTicks();

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
            if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN){
                if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_c){
                    if(cap == false){
                        cap = true;
                        std::cout<<"cap set to, true"<<std::endl;
                    }else{
                        cap = false;
                        std::cout<<"cap set to, false"<<std::endl;
                    }
                }
            }   
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                    running = false;
                    std::cout<<"Quit was pressed"<<std::endl;
            }
        }

        blitSurf(0,0,background,screen);
        if (msg_pos_y < 640){
            blitSurf(200,msg_pos_y,msg,screen);
            msg_pos_y++;
        }else{
            msg_pos_y = 0;
            blitSurf(200,msg_pos_y,msg,screen);
        }
        update();


        if ( (cap == true) && ( (SDL_GetTicks()-start) < (1000/FPS) ) ){
            SDL_Delay( (1000/FPS) - (SDL_GetTicks()-start) );
        }

        /* this works as well ??
        if ( cap == true ){
            SDL_Delay(1000/FPS);
        }
        */
    }

    cleanUp();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want 50 fps.

1000miliseconds / 50 = 20miliseconds delay.

But it takes time to render, compute physics, AI, whatever you are doing. Let's say that all this stuff I wrote takes 10miliseconds. You have 1000 miliseconds / (20ms delay + 10ms everything else) = 33.3 frames per second. You need to substract this 10ms from the delay.

Comment: cheers, But I wrote a test program which calls SDL_GetTicks() twice in one while loop iteration,  the first being at the very top and the second at the bottom. They both produce the same result and the timings are not different. Would the timing be different if the loop was more complex and had AI and physics and whatnot?.

Comment: Yes, they will be different if you will be doing something time consuming between them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but what he does is : once your main loop that runs your sdl app is finished (drawing blitting and all that stuff), time may have passed a bit while you were doing your stuff, for example if it took 10ms to do draw your frame, you have to wait (1000/FPS) - 10 ms until the next frame, otherwise your frame will lasts for too long.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought but, two calls to the SDL_GetTicks() function in one loop iteration gives the same result(?). so in the if statement the `fps.get_ticks()` really just returns 0 (`SDL_GetTicks() - startTicks;` from inside the get_ticks function). This is why I'm confused.